# Syntax error in stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

MySQL showing below Syntax error in following procedure.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 28
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE employee_salary_analysis_on_salary_type (IN salarytype VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

SELECT
  'city',
  'country',
  'grade',
  'FUNCTION',
  'level',
  'business_level_3',
  CASE WHEN salarytype = 'base_salary' THEN Sum(current_base_salary) WHEN salarytype = 'allow_salary' THEN Sum(
    allowance_1 + allowance_2 + allowance_3 + allowance_4 + allowance_5 + allowance_5 + allowance_6 + allowance_7 + allowance_8 + allowance_9 + allowance_10
  ) WHEN salarytype = 'target_salary' THEN Sum(current_target_bonus) WHEN salarytype = '4' THEN Sum(
    current_base_salary + allowance_1 + allowance_2 + allowance_3 + allowance_4 + allowance_5 + allowance_5 + allowance_6 + allowance_7 + allowance_8 + allowance_9 + allowance_10
  ) WHEN salarytype = '5' THEN Sum(
    current_base_salary + current_target_bonus
  ) WHEN salarytype = '6' THEN Sum(
    allowance_1 + allowance_2 + allowance_3 + allowance_4 + allowance_5 + allowance_5 + allowance_6 + allowance_7 + allowance_8 + allowance_9 + allowance_10 + current_target_bonus
  ) ELSE 0 END SalaryAsRequired
FROM
  employee_salary_details
GROUP BY
  'city',
  'country',
  'grade',
  'FUNCTION',
  'level',
  'business_level_3'; //line 28

END
```

Comment: Are you setting delimiters? AND mysql uses # for in line start of comment remove or amend //line 28 (what is this for anyway?) Otherwise this is syntactically correct.

Comment: Have you tried the query for a certain value of salarytype? Just to be sure that the query itself works fine.